# How To Rewrite URL in php using htaccess file. what change in php code

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new in .htaccess file. i m searching on net but i m not able to change and rewrite URL in PHP...
E.G

Show URL Like :

> localhost/web/site/view_project.php?vp=14

I want show my URL like

> localhost/web/site/project/14/

In php i m use this code

```
href="view_project.php?vp=<?php echo $c_id>" echo $c_project_title
```

In .htaccess file I'm using

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_project.php?vp=1& [L,R]
```

Now please tell what need to change in PHP Code and HTACCESS file...  I'm totally new in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP code to this:

```
href="project/<?php echo $c_id>" echo $c_project_title
```

And then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_project.php?vp=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi.. After This code Showing ERROR on this page.. Not Found

The requested URL /v_project.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @acre: Does `view_project.php` even exist under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` ?

Comment: Yes but i want change like ( domain.com/project/14 )

Comment: I understand that but since you commented that `equested URL /v_project.php was not found on this server` that's why I want to make sure first if target URL: `http://domain.com/view_project.php?vp=14` is serving your page or not.

Comment: i have a problem in localhost. online this file working. bt local host not... [ <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>]

Comment: You have to make sure to enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf and then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory on your localhost.

Comment: @acre: This is more than 6 months old Q&A. Request you to pls post a new question explaining your problem and I will attend to it.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp?noredirect=1#comment24847587_17162214]

Comment: Thanks I will attend that Q&A.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use $1 instead of 1 as you have it now, for more see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/389684/how-can-i-store-request-uri-in-a-variable-manipulate-it-and-then-use-it-in