# is this possible for URL Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know this might be a stupid question.

if I have an php or html code like this.

```
  <a href="http://localhost/site/author/detail.php?id=<?php $row['id']?>&name=<?php $row['name']?>">link</a>
```

is possible to rewrite it to something like below using htaccess?

```
http://localhost/site/author/(value for id here)/(value for name here)/
```

i've tried this.

```
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)$ ./author/detail.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

but it didnt work.

http.conf
I already uncomment the module by removing #.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

anyhelp would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You need 2 capturing placeholders, `RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)$ ./author/detail.php?id=$1&name=$2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/site/author/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/author/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: still not working and also my environment is windows 7 32bit. I also follow the instruction from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp but no luck.

Comment: What is location of this htaccess and what URL did you use for testing?

Comment: it is located in root folder of the project.
and I use the URL I posted. I just change the /site/ to the name of my project.

Comment: I think you need `RewriteBase /site/` (change to your folder name). Also is `/site/author/` a real directory?

Comment: yes..they are real.. it's like site is the name of the project. and author is the sub directory. I'll edit my question to show some of http.conf

I tried RewriteBase /site/ but still not working. I'm stack for this  for days now.

Comment: ok see updated code, remember it goes in `/site/author/.htaccess` file. Also tell me what exact URL do you see in your browser.

Comment: when I to go to http://localhost/site/author/10/blitzen12, I guess it worked, I can get the value for id which is 10 but the only problem now is that the designed is ruined. all css and js is not found.