# How can I get .htaccess to work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on my .htaccess for a school project. I'm trying to rewrite my URL so it looks nicer. That is, you have `localhost/website/public/profile/alex` and not `localhost/website/public/profile/index.php?username=alex`.

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/website/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^public/profile/?(.*)$ public/profile/index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Why is this not working? How can I make sure it will work?

Here is my file structure:

```
website/
    application/
    public/
        css/
        font/
        img/
        js/
        login/
        player/
        playlist/
        profile/
            const.php
            index.php
        register/
        const.php
        testplayer.php
    .htaccess
    website.sql
    index.php
    README.md
```

Comment: what is your document root? When you start having all these extra folders it causes confusion.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and told apache that he is allowed to parse .htaccess files? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html - keep in mind, that on Apache 2.4 the syntax differs.

Comment: My document root is all, then i have 2 sub folders a public where the user can do thing and a application with background information.

Comment: What do you mean all? I don't see an `all` folder in your list.

Comment: document root- what terminology is even that. project root is GrouPlaylist, and under public is accessible part- the one where apache redirects to index file, this pretty common project setup, dude...

Comment: Actually dude, no it's not. And it is referred to as "document root". http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: You say it's not working but what happens? Do you get an error or 404? I think it your rules that is wrong.

Comment: @AlexdeBeer don't delete questions after getting answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in apache configuration make sure you have set AllowOverride to all

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

check this link for xampp, don't forget to restart xampp after editing http.conf
[.htaccess not working on localhost with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp)

Comment: well, does xampp have apache? yes it does, because "A" in xAmpp stands for apache, check in xampp config how to enable override all.