# Symfony Routes not working for custom bundle when using directly

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have a Symfony setup at my local win-7 xampp with Directoryindex added and hosted pointing to C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\web.

I have .htaccess file which comes from create project, but unable to load the instance without app.php or app_dev.php. Rewrite module is working properly in the server instance.

Any idea on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to load the instance"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your XAMPP Apache configuration you should enable "AllowOverride" directive (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181304/410761).