# 404 Not Found error while using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this link:

```
<a href="admin.php?page=buyingreport">Buying Report</a>
```

To get a pretty URL, I've changed it to:

```
<a href="admin/buyingreport">Buying Report</a>
```

And this is my whole .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite [nC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,nC]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+)$ admin.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I always get 404 Not Found error "The requested URL /admin/buyingreport.php was not found on this server". Why was it redirect me to buyingreport.php?

The .htaccess file doesn't seem to work. Is there anything wrong with it? Or maybe with my link?

Anybody can help me, please?

Comment: Yes the link is in my admin.php.

Comment: do you have anyother rewrite rule?

Comment: @starkeen Yes  I Have. I've edited .htaccess in my post above.

Comment: Is htaccess insite the root folder?

Comment: @starkeen The .htaccess is in the same folder with my admin.php.

Comment: Do you mean "admin" ?

Comment: @starkeen Yes admin.php where I put href link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ admin.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It still direct me to buyingreport.php.

What I want is get this URL: www.mysite.com/admin/buyingreport.

While my actual page URL is: www.mysite.com/admin?page=buyingreport.

Comment: change the variable **id** with **page**
`RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ admin.php?page=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: if still doesn't work.check this answer maybe the problem from httpd.conf
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp)

Comment: Yes it works now. There is a little problem with js and css. But it's ok I'll find  the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great. the problem is come from the url because the url show like the content in a folder.
to fix it just add this code before you closing <head>
`<base href="http://maintarget/"/>`
change the http://maintarget/ with you your own main target.