# URL rewriting refused to work with codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite this URL:

> bookingstyles/search-treatment?search_service_hidden=89&service_group_id_hidden=

to give something like this:

> /bookingstyles/search-treatment/89/

I have tried using this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ http://localhost/bookingstyles/search-treatment.php?search_service_hidden=$1&service_group_id_hidden=$2 [L]
```

But I am still getting the same old URL.

Comment: Hi Addy, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to make the URLs clearer (more readable); remember, on this site it is encouraged for other users and you to [edit] your question to improve it as much as possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the code/link in your php file?

I think there is no need to specify the entire url in Rewite rule,instead you can use {HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Try this one

```
RewriteRule ^bookingstyles/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ search-treatment.php?id=$2&name=$1 [nc]
```

Setting up virtual host is a better solution.The following links may help.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

[.htaccess not working on localhost with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp)