# How can I remove slash from a url on php?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Hello actually I have this type of url

```
https://example.com/cart/index.php
https://example.com/cart/details.php
```

And I want show this

```
https://example.com/cart
https://example.com/cart/details
```

How can i do it using `.htaccess`?

I really try find on google but nothing help me correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the .index.php and the .php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Here you can get some more information: https://www.plothost.com/kb/how-to-remove-php-html-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: It work on local?

Comment: What are you using? Xamp or something like virtual machine?

Comment: Im using Xamp for it

Comment: It is possible that your .httacces dont work. Can you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp

Comment: Thanks that work