# X-Frame-Options: DENY does't work after adding .htaccess

Tags: html, xampp

I created a website on The XAMMP server in a folder. Inside the website I put a line`<iframe width="800" height="800">subwebsite1.html</iframe>`. I learn about X-frame-options and I wanted it to be tested. So i created a file .htaccess and i put there a line: `X-Frame-Options: DENY` and inside a subwebsite1.html
I put a line `<img src="foto1.jpg">`. And if I run my website on XAMPP server e.g. `\localhost\htdocs\index.html` it still works. So what did I wrong? I wanted to tested it and I fought it could't work any more but it still works. Neither did I sometging wrong nor I don't understand what it all means. Please help me...Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Do any directives in your `.htaccess` work? If not, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp) might be useful to you.

Comment: Nothing. I just simpy put one line.

X-Frame-Options: DENY
 
Is it not enought?:)

Comment: Try adding something else and see if that works. If it doesn't, then it's possible your .htaccess isn't working at all. The question I linked has some suggestions that might help.

Comment: I will take a peak tomorrow.... For now thanks a lot:)

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works....My htaccess didn't work properly. I do appeciate:)

Comment: Great! I submitted that as an answer -- please mark it as the answer that worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your `.htaccess` isn't enabled at all. Try putting something else in that file, and if it doesn't work, check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162214/htaccess-not-working-on-localhost-with-xampp).