# Error calling route when using XAMPP apache server Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I'm trying to check compability of my Laravel 8 project,
I have datatables with route

```
 ajax: {
                    url: "/detail/" + user_id,
                    data: function(d) {
                        d.kpi = $('#filter-kpi').val(),
                            d.search = $('input[type="search"]').val()
                    }
                },
```

when I acces it from artisan serve, it works pretty well (http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1000000004). But, when I access it using apache server in XAMPP (http://localhost/project-management-main/public/detail/1000000004), it return error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Is something wrong in my route?

Comment: Does this solve your Problem - [.htaccess not working on localhost with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181304/11691977)

Comment: I have try it, and still have same error

Answer (score 0):

if you js code in separate file than create an js global variable in your app layout.

```
<script>
  windows.base_url = "{{ url('/') }}";
</script>
```

Than in your js file access this

```
 ajax: {
             url: windows.base_url+"/detail/" + user_id,
             data: function(d) {
                   d.kpi = $('#filter-kpi').val(),
                   d.search = $('input[type="search"]').val()
               }
        },
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have try it and return error ```undefined/detail/1000000002?...```

Comment: where you have defined base url, i have updated my answer please check use windows not window

Comment: I defined it in my blade template (app.blade.php)

Comment: try to debug it console.log(windows.base_url) before calling ajax your url is right or not. also try to inspect or view source html and see base url is properly defined in your layout or not.