# Fetching records from database and display empty records once deleted in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi iam trying to fetch all the records from database but it is displaying only one record if there are more than 5 records also.I have tried with executing query in database it is working correctly can anyone help me regarding this.
If i delete the records and if there is no records in database it is displaying the delete option as well as the image option in front end.
Here is my code.

image.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    $res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs ";
    $result=mysql_query($res);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

blogimage.php

```
<form method="post" action="image.php" id="myform">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php include "image.php" ;?>   
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['blog_title'];?></td>
                <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

deleteblog.php

```
$id=$_GET['blog_id'];
$res = "DELETE 
FROM blogs 
WHERE blog_id=$id";
if($res)
{
echo "successfully deleted";
}
else{
echo "Failure";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this statement here,

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

You're fetching only one row from the result set.

**Solution:**

First of all, delete this line, `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` from your **image.php** page and then on **blogimage.php** page, loop through the result set to display all data, like this:

```
// your code

<?php 

    include "image.php";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
            <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>

// your code
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

---

**Edited:**

This is how you should perform DELETE operation.

```
<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);

    $id=$_GET['blog_id'];
    $res = "DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blog_id=$id";

    // Execute the query
    mysql_query($res);

    if(mysql_affected_rows()){
        echo "successfully deleted";
    }else{
        echo "Failure";
    }

?>
```

Comment: How can i pass id  to delete record

Comment: @Nagu Append the image id to your `href` attribute value, like this: `... href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`. And on **deleteblog.php** page get the id using `$id = $_GET['id'];` and delete that particular image.

Comment: As i given..... <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?<?php echo $row['blog_id'];?>" >Delete Blog</a></td>.... Here blog_id is my db table id and deleteblog.php i has given as ....$id=$_GET['blog_id'];.... But while executing it is getting error as undefined index blog_id and displaying message as successfully deleted but it is not deleting

Comment: @Nagu You're doing it wrong, it should be, `<td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?blog_id=<?php echo $row['blog_id']; ?>" >Delete Blog</a></td>` and on **deleteblog.php** page, catch it using `$id=$_GET['blog_id'];`

Comment: It is showing as successfully deleted but not deleting the record

Comment: @Nagu Did you correct the `href` attribute like I [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237534/fetching-records-from-database-and-display-empty-records-once-deleted-in-php-mys/35237607#comment58190078_35237607)? I don't know what's there in **deleteblog.php** page, what query are you using to delete the record?

Comment: Ya i have changed my href link to this <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?blog_id=<?php echo $row['blog_id'];?>" >Delete Blog</a></td> And my deleteblog.php has been updated above.

Comment: @Nagu You didn't execute the query. And use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to check how many rows are affected by the delete query.

Comment: Iam not getting what you are saying

Comment: @Nagu Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: i need a small favour last one how can i give hyperlink to bolg_title.......<td><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></td>  if iam trying to to add <a tag then it is not displaying the title name. as i used like this ...........<td><a href="<?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?>"></a></td>

Comment: As it should redirect to another to another page where i can show image as well as description

Comment: Do this, `...<td><a href="<?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?>"></a><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></td>`

Comment: title is displaying but hyperlink is not working if i click on that title it should redirect to another page where i can show that image and description in different format

Comment: @Nagu Oh, my mistake, it should be, `...<td><a href="<?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?>"><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></a></td>`

Comment: As i gave like this.....<td><a href="blogimages.php/<?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?>"><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></a></td> becuase when i click on the title it should redirect  to the page ....http://localhost/accounting/blogimages.php/Sample1

Comment: As i have created blogimages.php page but in the url it should print the title name also how can we do that

Comment: @Nagu That you can only do that using *.htaccess* file. Refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680295/how-to-rewrite-url-in-php-using-htaccess-file-what-change-in-php-code).

Comment: Iam not understanding how they have written that

Comment: @Nagu You need to learn how to write *htaccess* configuration file. Google it and learn. SO will help you if you get stuck at any point.

Comment: i have done like by comparing title names i should display the data for that purpose i have used in html .....<td><a href="blogimages.php?title=<?php echo $row['blog_title'];?>"><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></a></td>.....Here iam able to get the title name but in query if i use $id=$_GET['title'] and in where condition i have compared where blog_title=$id getting an error as Notice: Undefined index: title,Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Comment: @Nagu I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Form a separate question and ask.

Answer (score 0):

Change your php code from

```html
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    $res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs ";
    $result=mysql_query($res);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

to this

```html
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs ";
$result = mysql_query($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$data[] = $row;
}
?>
```

and html/php code from this

```html
<form method="post" action="image.php" id="myform">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php include "image.php" ;?>   
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['blog_title'];?></td>
                <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

to this

```html
<form method="post" action="image.php" id="myform">
    <table>
        <thead>
<?php if(!empty($data)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php include "image.php"; ?>   
<?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['blog_title']; ?></td>
                <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not working if there records then it is not showing one record also it is showing blank page

Comment: If there is no record in database then it will not show any data. what you want if there is no record in db ?

Comment: if there are records also it is not showing the records

Comment: it is working fine if there are no records but it should display the data if the records are there in db right but it is not working for that

Comment: Its working perfectly at myside. I have executed code. may be problem is in your image.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mysql_*` functions as these are deprecated. Instead use `mysqli_*.

And here is the code that you should try

**image.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accountant") or die(mysqli_error());
$res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs ";
$result= $connection->query($res);
?>
```

Your code on *blogimage.php* should go like this.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php include "image.php" ;
            while($row =  $connection->fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['blog_title'];?></td>
                    <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                    <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>   

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

**EDIT**

To delete a record, pass the id in the URL like in the code `deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` and then use the following code.

**deleteblog.php**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accountant") or die(mysqli_error());
    $deletequery = " DELETE FROM blogs WHERE id=".intval($_GET['id']);//your delete query
    $result= $connection->query($res);//execute query
    ?>
```

Comment: It is working but if i delete the record it is showing that it is successfully deleted but it is not deleting the record before it is deleting.

Comment: How can i pass the id for deleting the record

Answer (score 0):

Image.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs ";
$result=mysql_query($res);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Blogimage.php

```
<form method="post" action="image.php" id="myform">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php include "image.php"
 while($row =  $connection->fetch_assoc($result))
            {
;?>   
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['blog_title'];?></td>
                <td><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
                <td><a  class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?blog_id=<?php echo $row['blog_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" >Delete Blog</a></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

deleteblog.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['blog_id'];
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
$res = "delete  FROM blogs where blog_id=$id ";
$result=mysql_query($res);
header('Location: blogimage.php');
?>
```

Try this code

Comment: It is showing as successfully deleted but it is not deleting the record

Comment: always post what the OP had tried wrong rather just puttin up code